# How to produce hot water-soluble soap balls? What is their chemical background? What about medical capsules?

Tags: water, solubility

There are water-soluble balls for soap baths. Then there are medical capsules that disappear in mouth. Is it possible do this kind of capsules and water-soluble containers at home? If not, what do I need to do them? What is the chemistry behind them?

Comment: Empty gelatin capsules are readily available at drug stores (or used to be when my kids were smaller).  They dissolve pretty quickly.